# Buffered short I/O

Tags: java, buffer, java-io, short

How can read/write in a short buffer?

I'm trying to implement a BufferedReader and Writer for short values. Each times will be passed a short[] and will be read a short[].

But the java API doesn't have this interface, only byte[].

What's the best way to implement this feature?

Comment: Do you mean BufferedInput/OutputStream? Readers and Writers are for chars, not binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for your BufferedInputStream (not reader), you could try reading 2 bytes at the same time:

```
public synchronized int read(short[] s, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[s.length * 2];
    int read = read(b, off * 2, len * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < read; i+=2) {
        int b1 = b[i];
        int b2 = b[i+1];
        s[i/2] = (short) ((b1 << 8) | b2);
    }
    return read / 2;
}
```

For your BufferedOutputStream (not writer), you could try the reverse operation for writing 2 bytes at the same time.

Comment: You'll have to check that the bitwise stuff towards the end works OK.  A ByteBuffer as suggested by @akberc would be an alternative to that cryptic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could read/write the bytes and convert sets of two into shorts using ByteBuffer of length 2:

```
ByteBuffer put() to put the bytes into or putShort() when going the other way.   
ByteBuffer.getShort() to convert back into shorts.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [Reader interface](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html), and then extend the [writer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) to implement a writer that excepts short[].

Comment: Why would you use Reader and Writer for binary data?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a DataOutputStream around a BufferedOutputStream, and implement a method writeShortArray(short[]) that calls writeShort() iteratively over the array argument. Similarly for input.